# Multiple Text Box collaboration using google-drive-realtime-api

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to collaborate using multiple text boxes. For example, when textbox1 get changed in one Chrome browser window, textbox1 in another Chrome browser window must also get changed. When textbox2 get changed in one Chrome browser window, textbox2 in another Chrome browser window must also get changed. I have modified the existing code provided at https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart 
Here is my changed code...

**Index.html**

```
<!-- Text areas that will be used as our collaborative controls. -->
<input id="editor1" style="width:400px" placeholder="Type some text here..." autofocus><br />
<input id="editor2" style="width:400px" placeholder="Type some text here...">

function initializeModel(model) {
  var string1 = model.createString('Hello Realtime World1!');
  model.getRoot().set('text', string1);
  var string2 = model.createString('Hello Realtime World2!');
  model.getRoot().set('text', string2);
}

function onFileLoaded(doc) {
  var string1 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text');
  var string2 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text');

  // Keeping one box updated with a String binder.
  var textArea1 = document.getElementById('editor1');
  gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(string1, textArea1);

  var textArea2 = document.getElementById('editor2');
  gapi.drive.realtime.databinding.bindString(string2, textArea2);

....
```

When I tried to run this application and change the textbox1, textbox2 also get changed and in the other windows, both the textboxes get changed with the same text.

Please advise...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In initializeModel you are creating two collaborativeStrings, but assigning them both to the same key in the root "text".

Later on you are getting the same string "text" out of the root for both string1 and string2:

var string1 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text');
  var string2 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text');

You need to change one of those 'text' in both places to something else.

Comment: Thanks Cheryl for your reply!

Comment: As suggested, I have tried by changing the 'text' to 'text1' for the string2 but the second textbox stop collaborating.
    model.getRoot().set('text1', string2);
    var string2 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text1');

Please advise...thanks.

Comment: I suggest you re-post your code. Also if I were I'd use "text1" for string1 and "text2" for string2. this makes it less likely that you get things mixed up.

Comment: @Cheryl : Resolved. I have changed the code as you have suggested but this time, I have restarted the Chrome browser and it is now working. Thanks.